# Use Windows Narrator through .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, narrator

Is there a way to use text-to-speech capabilities of Windows Narrator in .NET applications? I want to use it or a similar service to read out loud strings from my C# application. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ms has a [speech API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.aspx) and now have a easily consumed managed interface.

Answer (score 0):

When using Visual Studio; in Solution Explorer.

1. Right Click '***References***' then click on '***Add Reference...***'.
2. Search for '***System.Speech***' under '***Framework***' then tick it.
3. Click '***OK***'

Then use code along the lines of the following:

```
System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer mainSpeechSynthesizer = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
mainSpeechSynthesizer.Speak("Test, test. Test! TEST.");
```

Here's a nice breakdown of how to use `System.Speech.Synthesis` with examples:

[Initialize and Manage the Speech Synthesizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/jj572475%28v%3Doffice.14%29)