# Make windows 10 narrator to speak some text

Tags: c++, c, winapi, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm making a GUI application in C++.
Is there a simple way to make the narrator of windows 10 to speak some text ?
Given of course that it is currently active.

A trick that sometimes works is to select some text in a text field and then focus it briefly. But

- It doesn't work all the time
- The focus is moved out and back. Even if it's for a short time, it's invasive and may disturb whatever the user is currently doing
- The text field must be present at some place on screen, what is not always desired

If possible, I would like a solution without these three issues.

Other screen readers, in particular Jaws and NVDA, provide API to do this.
I'm even the author of a library, [UniversalSpeech](https://github.com/qtnc/UniversalSpeech), which allow to make the currently running screen reader, if any, to speak text, abstracting the need to detect yourself which one is running.
Given that the narrator has greatly improved with the last 3 or 4 releases of windows 10, it would probably be interesting to support it, not only in my own program and for my particular usecase, but for everybody in my library.

However, I can't find any documentation or anything telling me if the narrator has an API similar to those of Jaws or NVDA.
In fact if there is currently no such API for Narrator, it would probably be interesting to suggest Microsoft to add one.

Note that this question is different from such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638965/use-windows-narrator-through-net)
where the answer suggests to use speech API directly. Using screen readers API and not speech API directly has great benefits:

- Screen reader users are used to specific voice settings (voice, rate, pitch, language and regional accents, etc.). The default settings set in the control panel may not at all be similar. It implies

  - whether the user must configure speech settings in the control panel, what is global for all applications; not very good
  - and/or managing application-specific speech settings in a business application which isn't at all devoted to speech stuff; it would be rather strange to find speech settings in a financial app  for example.
- Using both screen reader and independent speech engine simultenously means that both can speak at the same time, what is of course extremely annoying. In fact in practice it happens quite often, I have already tested.

So, is there a simple way to make narrator to speak some text ?

My program is in C++, the library is in C, so in theory I have access to the whole winapi, through LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress if needed. 
Please don't give any C# or VisualStudio-dependent solution.

Thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer

Comment: @VTT: Speech synthesis != scren reader.

Comment: You don't need to talk to a screen reader's API but implement the operating system's accessibility API. See [UI Automation and Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-msaa) and [Developing apps for accessibility](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/accessible-apps). The screen reader should then "take it from there".

Comment: Well, OK, certainly. But, how can I do the equivalent of a live region of web apps ? I have a multiline text field and lines should be spoken when they appear.

Comment: @QuentinC First you need evaluate if UI Automation can meet your requirement. For a quick test you can use [Inspect.exe tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) to see if it can read the text of a live region of web app? Then you may need learn UI Automation technique to implement your own application.

Comment: @RitaHan: I currently don't have a live region. I want to achieve the same behavior as in a live region, i.e. have some text read by the SR as it appears at the bottom of a multiline rich text field, but in a native GUI app. For info, I'm using WXWidgets.

Comment: @QuentinC If the target region (of Screen Reader like application) is in your own application that you have control of it, to make sure it can be read, you need expose controls in this region to UI Automation and make them visible to client applications, e.g. Screen Reader.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand at all your last comment and what I'm supposed to do. I have a multiline text field (wxTextCtrl). When some text is appended to it, I want the screen reader to read the text being just appended.

Comment: @QuentinC What I want to say is not all UI elements are accessible to client application(Screen Reader) by default. If the target application includes any custom controls, it need to implement UI Automation providers for those controls to make them accessible to accessibility client applications. That's why you need to check if the multiline text field (wxTextCtrl) is UI Automation enabled.

Comment: @RitaHanMSFt: Yes it is. A wxTextCtrl is nothing else than a RichEdit control. With Jaws, NVDA or the narrator, I can perfectly focus the field with tab and read the text using arrow keys.
What is missing is the ability to have new text automatically read when it is appended even if the focus isn't in the area. That's the definition of a live region in the web world. 
So I would like to have a solution to whether mark the field as a live region correctly, or a way to tell narrator to speak something in case narrator is the screen reader of the user, just as I can do it for Jaws and NVDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a while, I answer my own question !

IN fact, the simplest to make narrator speak something is probably to:

1. Define some label as being a live region
2. When something has to be spoken by narrator, change the text in the label and then send an update notification

Turning a label into a live region and sending a notification whenever the text changes is explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility-tools-docs/items/win32/text_livesetting

Live setting can be set to 0=off, 1=polite and 2=assertive. The meaning of polite and assertive are the same as in WAI ARIA.
Though as present (april 2021), narrator always interrupts speech as soon as the text of the label is replaced, even in polite mode.
What changes in assertive mode is that the text even take priority against interruptions due to normal keyboard navigation, i.e. you may not hear where you are when pressing tab, arrow keys, etc.
For that reason, I don't recommand it at all.

Note also that live setting only works on static text controls (win32 STATIC window class).
It is totally ignored when applied to text fields and text areas (win32 EDIT window class).

The label with live setting still works when placed off-screen or even hidden.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Microsoft Narrator doesn't expose the API for developers, and you can suggest a feature for it using [Feedback App](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub-app) on Windows 10.

> I want to achieve the same behavior as in a live region, i.e. have some text read by the SR as it appears at the bottom of a multiline rich text field, but in a native GUI app. For info, I'm using WXWidgets.

You can use the UI automation events to subscribe the property change of rich text field so that you can get notified when the text is updated. And since you are using third-party control, you also need to implement providers for any third party controls that do not include a provider. And below are links about UI automation provides and 
UI Automation events for your reference:

[UI Automation Events Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-eventsoverview)

[UI Automation Providers Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-providersoverview)

Comment: You can use the UI automation events to subscribe the property change of rich text field so that you can get notified when the text is updated => It seems that you have understood the problem in reverse: I know when the text is updated, since I'm updating it myself in my app. I want **the screen reader to be notified of my changes**. Probably the SR should subscribe to me rather than the opposite.

Comment: @QuentinC You were correct. As I mentioned that Microsoft Narrator doesn't support the scenario as you described. You need to implement the screen reader(Narrator) yourself and expose the API to other apps(your UI app) to allow subscribe the UI element or you can submit the feedback for Narrator.

Comment: How do aria-live regions work, then ? What does notify the screen reader ? If narrator support live regions in web browsers, then shouldn't be a way for me to equally notify the screen reader of changes in my GUI app ?
If effectively there's nothing, you have probably true, I need to suggest it to Microsoft. IN that case, what can/should I do to maximize chances to have something done ? Is there more specific narrator or accessibility teams to contact ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and any feedback for the Microsoft Narrator you can submit from [this link](https://microsoftaccessibility.uservoice.com/forums/307429-microsoft-accessibility-feedback?category_id=317275) directly